# Minio. I am unable to run a minio cluster. Getting this error on slave node

Tags: minio

I'm unable to create a minio cluster on 2 different nodes/systems. Getting this error on slave node where as master node is up and running which is the first ip machine,

"**Unable to read 'format.json' from [http://192.168.101.100:9000/minio/data1: Server](http://192.168.101.100:9000/minio/data1:%C2%A0Server) expects 'storage' API version 'v39', instead found 'v39' - *rolling upgrade is not allowed* - please make sure all servers are running the same MinIO version** (RELEASE.2021-09-09T21-37-07Z)

On running below command

docker run -d --name minio   --restart=always   --net=host   -e MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=minio   -e MINIO_SECRET_KEY=minio123   -v /data/minio1/data1:/minio/data1   -v /data/minio1/data2:/minio/data2 -v /data/minio1/data3:/minio/data3 -v /data/minio1/data4:/minio/data4  minio/minio server --address :9000   [http://192.168.101.100/minio1/data{​​​​​1...4}​​​​​ \](http://192.168.101.100/minio1/data%7B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B1...4%7D%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%C2%A0%5C) [http://192.168.101.101/minio1/data{​​​​​1...4}​​​​​](http://192.168.101.101/minio1/data%7B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B1...4%7D%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B)

Please tell me what I'm doig wrong. Thanks

Comment: clean up the old data ( volume) and re try.

Comment: Already did that, but still same issue